# Count data for last 10 days including days without any entries

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I want to count all data for each of last 10 days where some column have specific value. I manage to do this:

```
declare @start datetime = CAST(getdate() as date)
declare @end  datetime = dateadd(day, -10, @start)

;with amonth(day) as
(
     select @end as day
        union all
     select day + 1
        from amonth where day < CAST(@start as date)
)

select CAST(amonth.day as date) as dat, count(vrijeme) as c
from amonth 
left join Dnevnik on CAST(vrijeme as date) = CAST(amonth.day as date)
group by CAST(amonth.day as date) order by dat
```

It gives me a result like this:

```
dat         c

2017-01-21  0     <--- day without any record
2017-01-22  1
2017-01-23  1
2017-01-24  1
2017-01-25  1
2017-01-26  0     <--- day without any record
2017-01-27  27
2017-01-28  125
2017-01-29  190
2017-01-30  127
2017-01-31  319
```

But I don't want to count all data for each day, I want to count data where one column has specific value. So I thought it might be something like this (I added where clause):

```
declare @start datetime = CAST(getdate() as date)
declare @end  datetime = dateadd(day, -10, @start)

;with amonth(day) as
(
   select @end as day
       union all
   select day + 1
       from amonth
       where day < CAST(@start as date)
)
select CAST(amonth.day as date) as dat, count(vrijeme) as c 
from amonth 
left join Dnevnik on CAST(vrijeme as date) = CAST(amonth.day as date) 
where tipZapisa = 6
group by CAST(amonth.day as date) order by dat
```

but this code gives me results without those empty days (where count is 0)

```
dat          c

2017-01-22  1
2017-01-27  9
2017-01-28  67
2017-01-29  33
2017-01-30  46
2017-01-31  37
```

In the last result, I just want to include days which doesn't have any records.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It may just be a linguistic issue, but I find that having the "start" be more recent than the "end" is rather confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep your join LEFT , stop using LEFT columns in NULL -prohibiting predicates in WHERE. Include it in ON

```
with amonth(day) as
(
   select @end as day
       union all
   select day + 1
       from amonth
       where day < CAST(@start as date)
)
select CAST(amonth.day as date) as dat, count(vrijeme) as c 
from amonth 
left join Dnevnik on CAST(vrijeme as date) = CAST(amonth.day as date) 
                     and tipZapisa = 6
group by CAST(amonth.day as date) order by dat
```

Answer (score 0):

pre populate @START with the date of the 10th matching record, then feed it into your second query

```
SELECT @START = MIN(DQ.dat) FROM (select DISTINCT TOP 10 CAST(amonth.day as date) as dat
from  Dnevnik WHERE tipZapisa = 6 ORDER BY amonth.day as date DESC) DQ
```

then you should be able to return the actual 10 days with the matching condition